# How to add dynamic metadata to a singleton SLF4J logger in Java?

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

This is a Java question.

I have around 100 static functions that use a slf4j logger.
I want to add some metadata to standardise the logs - assume it's some kind of preamble that is a function of what processing is currently going on. 
How can I get the logger to print that metadata without going in to each of the static functions and changing them to explicitly add in the metadata.

e.g.

```
static Logger logger; ...
void mainProcessing() {
String file = "current_file.txt";
int line = 3;
...
func1();
func2();
...

}

void func1() {
...
logger.warn("some warning");
}
```

I'd like to see `"WARN: File current_file.txt, line 3, msg: some warning"` in the logs.

Any ideas?

(Prefer not to have to change each of the `func1()` functions obviously, if possible)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify print format. However beware, that obtaining line number and/or file will greatly decrease your application performance. This is not C++, Logback will probably create a Throwable object for each line, to retrieve the stacktrace and extract the line number and file name.

Regarding line:

> L / line   Outputs the line number from where the logging request was
>   issued.
>
> Generating the line number information is not particularly fast. Thus,
>   its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Regarding file:

> F / file  Outputs the file name of the Java source file where the
>   logging request was issued.
>
> Generating the file information is not particularly fast. Thus, its
>   use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#file

Sample logback.xml configuration would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"}: %-5p %F:%L [%t] %c{0}: %M - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Better to **redesign your code**, that messages are **more verbose** and **not unique**, containing the context and required data to debug it by a person that does not know the code very well (your future co-worker)